# В чем отличие объявления структур?

Tags: c++, c

Вариант 1:

```
typedef struct StructName
{
    int a,b,c;

} Name;
```

Вариант 2:

```
typedef struct
{
    int a,b,c;

} Name;
```

В чем отличие этих двух объявлений?

Comment: В первом случае вы можете одним из полей можете сделать указатель на эту структуру: struct StructName *name;

Comment: Кирилл Малышев а во втором нет? Name *name нельзя?

Comment: Ну попробуйте. Это всё больше к Си относится, т.к. в C++ можно писать без struct сразу.

Comment: Кирилл Малышев пишу в g++ и все замечательно работает

Comment: Скомпилируйте Си-код https://ideone.com/nH4mDZ https://ideone.com/0PnqO0